# Multiple default content type in spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot

We are migrating monolithic netty web application into multiple spring boot microservices. Currently the consumers are not passing Content-Type header in the request.

To support that i have added below code in my application

```
    @Override
  public void configureContentNegotiation(final ContentNegotiationConfigurer configurer) {
    configurer
        .defaultContentType(APPLICATION_XML)
```

But the problem is i have endpoints with application/json as content type.

Is it possible to have default content type based on url's or is it possible to add headers in the request using some filter or interceptor.

Answer (score 1):

If you add mediaType to your configuration it will enable content negotiation for whichever media types you want.

Spring checks three things, in this order

- Add an extension to your request, e.g. `/endpoint` becomes `/endpoint.json` if you want JSON
- Add the `format` parameter, e.g. `/endpoint` becomes `/endpoint?format=json`
- Add the requisite `Accept` header, e.g. `Accept=application/json` (unless you configure the `ContentNegotiationConfigurer` to ignore the `Accept` header.

```
@Override
public void configureContentNegotiation(final ContentNegotiationConfigurer configurer) {
  configurer
    .defaultContentType(APPLICATION_XML)
    .mediaType("json", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    .mediaType("xml", MediaType.APPLICATION_XML);
}
```

Configured in this manner, your endpoints will marshal XML unless overridden by one of the means described above.

If you cannot make changes to your clients to ask that they request the format they expect, you can override the behavior of a specific endpoint by adding `produces` to the mapping, like this

```
@GetMapping("/endpoint", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
```

or

```
@RequestMapping("/endpoint", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
```

This answer assumes that you've imported the correct dependencies into your project, you'll need the jackson XML mapper.  Also, assuming you leave the content negotiation configuration in place, I would highly recommend that on your methods that you specify produces, that you include `produces = {"application/xml", "application/json"}` just in case your clients start following the proper specs and send an Accept header.  Also, note that you'll need to make sure your objects are annotated with at a minimum, `@XmlRootElement`

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: we can't make any changes to the client. like adding extension to the endpoint or adding accept header

Comment: @RamachandranMurugaian See my edit

Comment: I am receiving following error "Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type '' not supported]".

Comment: @RamachandranMurugaian See my edits, you'll need to add some additional imports that I assumed you already had in place.